# Linux: checking of incoming UDP datagrams

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, udp, linux-device-driver

I'm working with special-purpose hardware that is connected on a 10G Ethernet link. I've got some questions on the handling of incoming datagrams, as follows:

1. What happens if the NIC discovers an incorrect link-level Ethernet CRC? Some searching shows that errors may not be reliably reported ([here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2009/10/msg01174.html), for instance). Can I expect to get better stats from more recent kernels (2.6 - 3.10?)
2. What does the kernel actually check before deciding whether to return a packet to a `recv`? I'm guessing that for IPv4, the IPv4 header checksum must be correct, but what about the optional UDP header checksum?
3. Can `recv` ever return 0 for a UDP/`SOCK_DGRAM`?
4. For a non-blocking `SOCK_DGRAM` socket, does `recv` always return the entire packet when data is available? I guess it has to, but it's not obvious from the docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Modern EMACs are capable of performing the IP, TCP, and UDP checksum (generation and) verification in hardware, offloading it from the kernel.  When any checksum error is detected, the typical EMAC can be configured to discard the entire frame.  [**NETIF_F_RXCSUM**](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/NETIF_F_RXCSUM) can be used to enable this hardware capability.    BTW kernel versions 2.6 - 3.10 are no longer considered *"recent"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. My knowledge may be out of date here, but historically, packets with FCS errors were not delivered at all *and* were not counted toward the interface statistics. The Ethernet layer error counts *are* usually reported by `ethtool -S <interface>`. The problem has always been that the interface statistics were maintained above the driver level and there was no standard API internally for network drivers to report those statistics. (Also, of course, in the very old days of 10Mb half duplex, collisions happened pretty frequently and Ethernet layer statistics weren't terribly informative as to your own adapter's behavior.)
2. You should not receive a packet if its IP header checksum is wrong, or if the UDP checksum is wrong *when* a checksum is provided (i.e. non-zero).
3. Yes. If you provide a zero length buffer, you will receive the next incoming datagram but then the entire content will be truncated, resulting in a return value of zero. Also, UDP permits zero-length datagrams: so if you receive a datagram with no content, the return value would also be zero. Aside from those two cases, I don't believe you'll get a return value of zero.
4. Yes, you should get the entire datagram *provided* there is space in your buffer. Otherwise, no. If you don't provide enough space to hold the entire datagram, the part that doesn't fit is discarded (*i.e.* your next `recv` will get a subsequent packet, not the end of the truncated one).